# Android: ScrollView gets messy when scrolling?

Tags: android, scrollview

I've seen this issue a few times and haven't found a fix for it.  The contents of my ScrollView blur when scrolling.  Below are the xml layout for the view, and images showing the issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TableLayout 
        android:stretchColumns="1,2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TableRow>
            <TextView 
                android:text="" 
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>
            <TextView 
                android:text="Column 1" 
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>
            <TextView 
                android:text="Column 2" 
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView 
                android:text="Row1: " 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </TextView>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </CheckBox>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </CheckBox>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView 
                android:text="Row2: " 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </TextView>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </CheckBox>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </CheckBox>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView 
                android:text="Row3: " 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </TextView>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </CheckBox>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </CheckBox>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView 
                android:text="Row4: " 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </TextView>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </CheckBox>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </CheckBox>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView 
                android:text="Row5: " 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </TextView>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </CheckBox>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </CheckBox>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView 
                android:text="Row6: " 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </TextView>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </CheckBox>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </CheckBox>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView 
                android:text="Row7: " 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </TextView>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </CheckBox>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </CheckBox>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView 
                android:text="Row8: " 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </TextView>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </CheckBox>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </CheckBox>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView 
                android:text="Row9: " 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </TextView>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </CheckBox>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </CheckBox>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you just seeing this problem with this specific content, or are you demonstrating a wider issue? If it's the former, I'd highly recommend using a ListView rather than a ScrollView.

Comment: Wider issue, I often see it when scrolling in ListViews.

Comment: Is it possibly your video card? I'm on Linux, I had a problem this weird with a buggy Flash plugin: if I moved the emulator over a flash banner in the browser I could see it through.

Comment: @bigstones.  I doubt it.  I see it both on my emulator (running on windows 7), and on my Samsung Galaxy Tablet.

Comment: Ok. This is fixed by setting a background color for the ScrollView.

Comment: Why are you writing `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in the `ScrollView`? Use `fill_parent`.

Comment: @Macarse. I tried this, it did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was resolved by setting a background color for the ScrollView or a theme for the activity in which it is displayed.

Comment: Didn't help me!! `<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"` and `<ScrollView android:background="#00000000" >`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the rep to comment.
The accepted answer solved my issue.
But to be clearer: @IronBlossom and others who will have the same problem.
You need to set the color without setting alpha to 0. I mostly use RGBA so it's new to me, but this works

```
android:background="#000000"
<!-- This one has 6 zeros -->
```